# Juntar array de objetos por chave

Tags: javascript, array

O cenário é que estou recebendo um csv, lendo ele com o Papaparse e tentando juntar todos os valores com a mesma chave em um único array, e depois botar tudo em um array (pra fazer um map depois)

Por exemplo: O csv lido me retorna:

```
[{
  name: "Bruno",
  city: "Santo Augusto"
  age: "28"
},
{
  name: "Fulano",
  city: "Santo Augusto"
  age: "21"
},
{
  name: "Paulo",
  city: "Santo Augusto"
  age: "24"
}]
```

e eu tou tentando fazer com que vire um array assim:

```
[
  ["Bruno", "Fulano", "Paulo"],
  ["Santo Augusto", "Santo Augusto", "Santo Augusto"],
  ["28", "21", "24"]
]
```

O maior problema é que essas chaves vão ser aleatórias. Eu pensei em juntar pelo index do objeto mas não achei uma forma de fazer isso.

Com chaves aleatórios quero dizer que não necessariamente vai ter um name ou city, tudo isso vai vir aleatório do header do csv em que está sendo lido pelo parser.

Comment: Explique com detalhes o quer dizer com chaves aleatórias.

Comment: Da para fazer controlando as colunas com um `Set`. [Fiz aqui um esboço da solução](https://jsfiddle.net/tLfsw68j/1/), mas não funcionará caso tenha itens com chaves diferentes **e** o número de colunas esperado seja igual para todas as ocorrências no resultado

Comment: @Sorack  Realmente não tinha visto na pergunta que as chaves eram aleatórias.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Se as chaves vão ser aleatórias, ou seja, não necessariamente vai existir um `name` ou `city` em todos os objetos, o que da pra fazer é isso :

```js
const lista = [
  {
    name: "Bruno",
    city: "Santo Augusto",
    age: "28"
  },
  {
    name: "Fulano",
    age: "21"
  },
  {
    name: "Paulo",
    city: "Santo Augusto",
    age: "24",
    teste: "123123",
  }
]

var resultObject = {}
var result = []
lista.forEach((item) => {
  Object.entries(item).forEach(k => {
    const key = k[0]
    const value = k[1]
    if (!Object.keys(resultObject).find(p => p === key)) {
      resultObject[key] = [value]
    } else {
      resultObject[key].push(value)
    }
  })
})
Object.values(resultObject).forEach(i => {
  result.push(i)
})
console.log(result)
```

Nessa situação, eu percorri os elementos dentro da lista, e peguei cada chave e valor através desse  `Object.entries(item).forEach...`.

O `const key = k[0]` é o nome da propriedade e o `const value = k[1]` é o valor, então eu criei um objeto auxiliar `resultObject`, para armazenar os valores com as mesmas chaves dentro de uma lista.

Nesse `if else` estou verificando se a propriedade dentro do `resultObject` já existe, e se não existe crie ela.

No final, o `resultObject` fica mais ou menos assim :

```js
{
  name: [ 'Bruno', 'Fulano', 'Paulo' ],
  city: [ 'Santo Augusto', 'Santo Augusto' ],
  age: [ '28', '21', '24' ],
  teste: [ '123123' ]
}
```

Ai é só percorrer os valores e armazená-los na sua lista:

```js
Object.values(resultObject).forEach(i => {
  result.push(i)
})
```

Comment: Como o código não é claro/auto explicativo seria legal explicar o que ele faz, qual o passo-a-passo, lógica, etc